# How to resolve Permission denied for my new log file

Tags: php, linux, logging

I'm trying to get logging enabled on a PHP page that I'm debugging, but I get this permissions error below.  The router log file has a permission of 644, the same as other log files in the /var/log directory, so I'm not sure what is wrong.

> Warning: error_log(/var/log/router): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/production/ot1/public_html/router.php
>   on line 33

Any suggestions?  Thanks!

Comment: Who is the owner of the file?

Comment: Owner and Group are both recordau. I tried changing the permission to 775 just now too without success.

Comment: Given its running from within /var/www then the user running it is probably www-data or maybe apache. 775 still doesn't give write permission to all users, if you want everyone to have read/write then it's 666 but it's better to identify the correct user and give ownership of the file to them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the owner and group of the log file and see if the application that should write to it is running as the user that is the file's owner.

You can do it using `ls -l`, e.g.

```
$ ls -l /tmp/plugin156832448
srwxr-xr-x 1 nomad nomad 0 Apr 20 14:42 /tmp/plugin156832448
```

In this example the owner and the group are both `nomad`. As you can see the file is not writable by everyone. It has permissions set as `srwxr-xr-x` or `1755`.

If you want your file to make it writable for everyone then you can do it using `chmod o+w /var/www/production/ot1/public_html/router.php` but it is a bad decision compared to fixing ownership of files.